# how sort rows with respect of a group?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Hi i have panda data frame. I wana sort data with respect of a group id and sorting with respect of order

```
id    title      order
2      A           2
2      B           1
2      C           3
3      H           2
3      T           1
```

out put:

```
id    title      order
2      B           1
2      A           2
2      C           3
3      T           1
3      H           2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not aggregating, you can sort by multiple columns to get the output you want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                   'title': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'H', 'T'],
                   'order': [2, 1, 3, 2, 1]})
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'order'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id title  order
1   2     B      1
0   2     A      2
2   2     C      3
4   3     T      1
3   3     H      2
```